# Custom favicon in Aura Lightning App

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, favicon

how can I change the favicon of an Aura Lightning App ?
By Aura App I mean an

```html
<aura:application></aura:application>
```

which is access directly via the URL : https://myorg.lightning.force.com/c/myapp.app

I want to replace the default salesforce favicon with one provided via http

Comment: Could you more elaborate your question? You mean changing image in app created using Lightning App Builder or favicon (icon displayed on the tab) of custom lightning:application?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my post to be more specific